# What are the practical differences between Redux and Context/Providers in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, provider

I'm a new developer and I'm having trouble understanding the importance of Redux when things like `createContext`, `useContext`, and Providers exist. In my naive observation it seems like you can do everything Redux can do (minus the state-tracking dev tools extensions) with just a global context provider at the top level component.

For example, something like this:

```
function App() {
  const [stateOne, setStateOne] = useState();
  const [stateTwo, setStateTwo] = useState();

  return (
    <ContextProvider shared={{
      stateOne,
      setStateOne,
      stateTwo,
      setStateTwo
    }}>
      ...
    </ContextProvider>
  )
}
```

Now all descendant components have access to global state, which seems like the main point of Redux. Am I missing an important differentiating factor here about Redux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Context and Redux are very different tools that solve different problems, with *some* overlap.

Context is *not* a "state management" tool. It's a Dependency Injection mechanism, whose only purpose is to make a single value accessible to a nested tree of React components.  It's up to you to decide what that value is, and how it's created.  Typically, that's done using data from React component state, ie, `useState` and `useReducer`.  So, you're actually doing all the "state management" yourself - Context just gives you a way to pass it down the tree.

Redux is a library and a pattern for separating your state update logic from the rest of your app, and making it easy to trace when/where/why/how your state has changed.  It also gives your whole app the ability to access any piece of state in any component.

In addition, there are some distinct differences between how Context and (React-)Redux pass along updates.  Context has some major perf limitations - in particular, any component that consumes a context *will* be forced to re-render, even if it only cares about part of the context value.

Context is a great tool by itself, and I use it frequently in my own apps.  But, Context doesn't "replace Redux".  Sure, you can use both of them to pass data down, but they're not the same thing.   It's like asking "Can I replace a hammer with a screwdriver?". No, they're different tools, and you use them to solve different problems.

For more details, see my posts:

- [Why React Context is Not a "State Management" Tool (and Why It Doesn't Replace Redux)](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2021/01/context-redux-differences/)
- [Redux - Not Dead Yet!](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/03/redux-not-dead-yet/)
- [When (and when not) to Reach for Redux](https://changelog.com/posts/when-and-when-not-to-reach-for-redux)
- [React, Redux, and Context Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/01/blogged-answers-react-redux-and-context-behavior/).
- [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is when you use arrays. You cannot dynamically create React Context slices for the elements of the array. So when the array changes, all components fetching the array will re-render, even if they are only interested in one element that didn't change. In Redux you can use a selector to effectively re-render the component only when the element of the array changes. This is the basic performance difference between the two. Said that, [react-context-slices](https://react-context-slices.github.io) can help you, because with it you can define either Redux slices or React Context slices:

```js
// slices.js
import getHookAndProvider from "react-context-slices"

export const {useSlice, Provider} = getHookAndProvider({
  count1: {initialArg: 0}, // React Context slice
  count2: { // Redux slice
    initialState: 0,
    reducers: {
      increment: (state) => state +1
    }
  },
  // rest of slices, either React Context or Redux slices
})
```

```js
// app.js
import {useSlice} from "./slices"

const App = () => {
  const [count1, useCount1] = useSlice("count1");
  const [count2, reduxDispatch, {increment}] = useSlice("count2");

  return <>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount1(c => c + 1)}>+</button>{count1}
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => reduxDispatch(increment())}>+</button>{count2}
    </div>
  </>
}
```